# How to Disable automatic addition of CORS header in Spring SockJS module of Spring Websocket

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I have used Spring SockJs in my project for some websocket support. As per documentation, spring sockjs library adds CORS header based on origin in the incoming request -unless it detects the header added by servlet filter or by any mechanism. http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html (section 21.3.6 CORS Headers for SockJS)

I am not sure if it's a good Idea to automatically add a header, but for my use case, I want to disable addition of any header. So I either explicitly add or drop it -Spring SOCKJS should not add it automatically.

Is there a way to do that? I explored SockJsService API but could not figure out much http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/sockjs/support/AbstractSockJsService.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a clear path for doing this right now. Also, I didn't understand what's actually bothering you: allowing other origins, or having HTTP response headers you didn't yourself?

In any case, those headers are the sensible defaults you probably want if want to make sure all SockJS transports work on all supported clients.

Since this is probably not the best place to discuss this, you can open a new [JIRA issue](http://jira.spring.io) for the Spring Framework project (module "Messaging:Websocket") and explain your use case/motivations for this.

Comment: Brian, In my use case, CORS IP white listing is taken care by external system (Say some interceptor), if some how it is bypassed, sockjs will allow connection from any origin -opening a security loophole. Thats why I want to disable it so that even if some one hacks into sockjs url directly, browser will throw a CORS error

Comment: So I guess those headers are set independently by an apache/nginx server and so not set at the servlet level? In that case, could you open a JIRA issue?

Comment: That's correct. Yes, I will open a JIRA issue and update URL here.